# Print all user's followers

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to print all the followers the person that owns a profile page has. Here is my following table that shows the following relationship:

```
class Following(models.Model):
    target = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='followers', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    follower = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='targets', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} is followed by {}'.format(self.target, self.follower)
```

I am also using Django's auth User model.

**views.py**

```
class FollowersView(DetailView):
    model = User
    slug_field = 'username'
    template_name = 'profile/followers.html'

    def get_profile_followers(user):
        return user.followers.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["follower_list"] = get_profile_followers(self.object) # self.object is user profile
        return context
```

In the template, I am doing this:

```
    {% for follower in follower_list %}
        <h1>{{ follower }}</h1>
    {% endfor %}
```

But, I get this instead: Chris is followed by John. This is correct, Chris is followed by John, however, I want to display only John's user and John's attributes like `avatar`, `follower_count`, etc. that are fields in the `User` table. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on text, I suppose you get `Following` instance as `{{ follower }}` value. So you can just use `.` syntax to get follower attributes like this:

```
{% for follower in follower_list %}
    {{ follower.follower.username }}
    {{ follower.follower.avatar }}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that accessing related objects through `.` required additional DB query. So you may use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) in you queryset for optimization:

```
def get_profile_followers(user):
    return user.followers.all().select_related('follower')
```

Comment: How can I use `select_related` in my queryset?

Comment: @user2896120 In your `get_profile_followers` method You need to add somethng like this `return = queryset.select_related('follower')`. See details and examples in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: hmm, i'm trying to do: `user.objects.select_related('followers')` but i'm getting an error that says: `Manager isn't accessible via User instances`

Comment: @user2896120 can you add `get_profile_followers` code to the question?

Comment: @user2896120 sorry, missed it. Try to change it like this: `return user.followers.all().select_related('followers')`.

Comment: Just wondering how this will help in optimizing the code? Doesn't user.followers.all() do the job already? What does select_related help in doing in this example?

Comment: @user2896120 `user.followers.all()` returns `Following` instances. `select_related('follower')` will add to it precomputed `follower` attribute. So `{{follower.follower.username}}` will not hit DB. UPD it should be `user.followers.all().select_related('follower')`.

Comment: Interesting, so each time I access any follower attribute it'll hit the db? For example, {{follower.follower.username}} and {{follower.follower.avatar}} will hit the db a total of two times?

Comment: @user2896120 no. After first call `{{follower.follower}}` will be cached. But in case of using `select_related` even first call will not hit DB since `{{follower.follower}}` already has been prepopulated with `select_related('follower')`.